# Xamarin android java service started form xamarin android using jni stops when app is closed

Tags: java, android, mono, java-native-interface, xamarin.android

Trying to get parse push notification working in xamarin.android. Parse sdk for .net does not provied methods for working with push notification. So I tried to wrap jar libraries. In my xamarin app I start this service using jni

```
[Application]
public class MyApplication : Application
{
    public MyApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership ownerShip) : base(handle, ownerShip)
    {
    }

    public override void OnCreate ()
    {
        base.OnCreate ();
        Com.Parse.Parse.Initialize (this, "4UkwfaiYctiyx5AFjlLgCDzpzegOK6I53W3MwwAO", "5SaqZT2dGuy9N6poizKjrri4iLVGTf2Wq1tfRdja");
        //Com.Parse.PushService.SetDefaultPushCallback (this, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(MainActivity)));
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource

        SetDefaultPushCallback(this,Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(MainActivity)));
    }
    public static unsafe void SetDefaultPushCallback (global::Android.Content.Context p0, global::Java.Lang.Class p1)
    {
        IntPtr id_setDefaultPushCallback_Landroid_content_Context_Ljava_lang_Class_=IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr class_ref = JNIEnv.FindClass("com.parse.PushService");
        if (id_setDefaultPushCallback_Landroid_content_Context_Ljava_lang_Class_ == IntPtr.Zero)
            id_setDefaultPushCallback_Landroid_content_Context_Ljava_lang_Class_ = JNIEnv.GetStaticMethodID (class_ref, "setDefaultPushCallback", "(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/Class;)V");
        try {
            JValue* __args = stackalloc JValue [2];
            __args [0] = new JValue (p0);
            __args [1] = new JValue (p1);
            JNIEnv.CallStaticVoidMethod  (class_ref, id_setDefaultPushCallback_Landroid_content_Context_Ljava_lang_Class_, __args);
        } finally {
        }
    }
```

Method `setDefaultPushCallback` starts a service.  The problem is that this service stops when I close the app. The java version of app starts a service that continues to run even when app is closed.

Comment: Solved. The reason of such behaviuor was that i had debugger attached. Without debugger everything works as it should